# How to launch iOS/iPadOS apps from shell in macOS with Apple Silicon?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, apple-silicon

Related topic:
[How to get an application executable path from Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334621/how-to-get-an-application-executable-path-from-terminal)

With macOS native apps, I can launch them directly form Terminal, for example.

```
garmin@M2 ~ % /Applications/CotEditor.app/Contents/MacOS/CotEditor
```

However this doesn't seem to work with with apps not available natively for macOS, but for iOS or iPadOS, let's say eBay:

[image: eBay for iPad running on macOS with Apple silicon]

It does not launch:

```
garmin@M2 ~ % /Applications/eBay.app/Wrapper/eBay.app/eBay
zsh: killed     /Applications/eBay.app/Wrapper/eBay.app/eBay
```

Any idea if this is even possible to do? How can I launch it from shell or bash?

Answer (score 1):

You can start applications from a shell by running

```
open -a APPLICATION.app
```

Comment: Right, it works, but why doesn't work launching the ex like it does with CotEditor? This is what I want to know also.

Comment: @Smeterlink The eBay binary which finally gets executed is in `/private/var/folders/8b/...` (run `ps aux | grep -i ebay` to check on your system), so I assume that some preparation steps are required which the shell isn't aware of (the shell simply runs `exec()` on the binary).

Comment: that must be it, because running such binary directly from the location `/private/var/folders/x9/.../X/.../d/Wrapper/eBay.app/eBay` just quits with `Killed: 9`.